# How to disable datepicker UI for a mobile device

Tags: javascript, date-preferences, css

I like the datepicker UI, but many people don't.

We require date of birth on a few forms.  Each week I get at least one complaint that someone can't fill out the form on a mobile. Not sure if a bug or user error. I think the easiest thing is to disable it for mobiles.  Ideally, have an icon to trigger it.

I was wondering if there is a clever /safe way to use css for this so we can use @media queries to disable for mobile devices.

I was experimenting with

#ui-datepicker-div {
z-index: -9999;
display: none!important;
}

which seems to work, but disables validation.  Looking for any other keen ideas.

Comment: I did find a way to disable popup on focus: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the native datepicker of the mobile device, the field needs to have `type="date"`. So your code to disable the datepicker popup and use the native device's instead might look like:

```
(function($) {
  $.ui.datepicker.prototype.options.focus = "button";

  $(document).on('crmLoad', function($region) {
    $('input.dateplugin', $region).each(function() {
      this.type = 'date';
    });
  });
})(CRM.$);
```

Comment: @sonicthoughts did that work for you?